# Option -fembed-bitcode disappear when linking shared library

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, dylib, bitcode

I try to compile several open-source libraries for iOS as shared libraries with bitcode. I've added flag `-fembed-bitcode` into CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. Compilation completes normally but some of resulting libraries (curl for example) has no bitcode in them (I've checked it with `otool -l lib.dylib | grep LLVM`).

My investigation shows that flag `-fembed-bitcode` simply disappears from linker command line when dylib is linking though in Makefile there is direct usage of LDFLAGS in this place. How `-fembed-bitcode` can be dissapear from LDFLAGS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `-fembed-bitcode` flag disappearing is that library use libtool for linking and it [strips](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Stripped-link-flags.html) unknown flags by default:

> When creating a shared library, but not when compiling or creating a
>   program, libtool drops some flags from the command line provided by
>   the user. This is done because flags unknown to libtool may interfere
>   with library creation or require additional support from libtool, and
>   because omitting flags is usually the conservative choice for a
>   successful build.
>
> If you encounter flags that you think are useful to pass, as a
>   work-around you can prepend flags with -Wc, or -Xcompiler to allow
>   them to be passed through to the compiler driver (see Link mode).
>   Another possibility is to add flags already to the compiler command at
>   configure run time:
>
> ./configure CC='gcc -m64'

So I've just add `-Wc,-fembed-bitcode` flag to LDFLAGS in addition to `-fembed-bitcode` and library compiles with bitcode.